# can a sharepoint app be added several times?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I want to be able to add an app multiple times in sharepoint. Just like a  list or a survey. I am creating a sharepoint hosted app and deploying it on the app catalogue of my organization. I want to reuse the app multiple times in the same site collection but want to bind it to different list every time in the host url. So I have thought of using the app multiple times and binding it to different list each time the app is installed. All answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, this isn't possible by default. You can try to work around this limitation, see e.g. this: http://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/host-multiple-provider-hosted-sharepoint-apps-within-a-single-assosiated-web-application/ , but even in this example the person stopped trying.

Why can't you create your app such that it can handle multiple lists?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to change your app little bit.

If you want to use the same app with multiple lists... Then please add the list name in configuration of   app.

Like in Simple web part, we create web part properties, **if same web part needs to fetch or insert data in different lists in same site/site collection.**